# Aibohphobia SPOJ

Tags: c#, dynamic-programming, memoization

I am trying to [solve this exercise.](http://www.spoj.com/problems/AIBOHP/)

I have a solution, as below, but I am getting `Time Limit Exceeded` error. I want to learn why this code is inefficient since I am doing memoization.

```
namespace Aibohphobia
{
    class Test
    {
        static Dictionary<string, int> memo = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            string num = Console.ReadLine();
            int N = int.Parse(num);
            string input = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                memo = new Dictionary<string, int>();
                input = Console.ReadLine();
                int count = new Test().insert(input, 0, input.Length - 1);
                Console.WriteLine(count);
            }
            return 0;
        }

        int insert(string input, int start, int end)
        {
            int count = 0;
            var key = start + "_" + end;

            if (start >= end)
                return 0;            
            if (memo.ContainsKey(key))
                return memo[key];
            if (input[start] == input[end])
            {
                count += insert(input, start + 1, end - 1);
            }
            else
            {
                int countLeft = 1 + insert(input, start + 1, end);
                int countRight = 1 + insert(input, start, end - 1);
                count += Math.Min(countLeft, countRight);
            }

            memo.Add(key, count);
            return count;
        }    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *memoizing* your results in a `Dictionary<string, int>`, which is, essentially, a hash table. It means that every time you want to retrieve a value for a given key, you must calculate the hash function of the key.

In this case, since the type of your key is `string`, the evaluation of the hash function is surely slowing your execution. I suggest that you *memoize* your values for the DP in `int[][] matrix`, therefore you can retrieve the values you want much faster.

In order to achieve that, you will have figure out how to map your `strings` to `ints`. You can find a brief tutorial on how to do that here: [String Hashing for competitive programming](https://threads-iiith.quora.com/String-Hashing-for-competitive-programming), where the author explains simple *string hashing* techniques.